# Parse Dictionary Values Python

Tags: python, dictionary

How could I parse the `dictionary` below, so that it's `values` only contain ticket numbers?

Current Dictionary:

```
{'8.8.8.8': 'Open Menu  10A-003272 10A-003328 10A-003652', '8.8.8.9': '10A-003069 10/21/2016', '8.8.8.10': 'Open Menu  10A-003145 10/21/2016'}
```

Objective Dictionary:

```
{'8.8.8.8': '10A-003272 10A-003328 10A-003652', '8.8.8.9': '10A-003069', '8.8.8.10': '10A-003145'}
```

Code used to make dictionary:

```
with open(esccbList, 'r') as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        d[line.strip()] = next(f, '').strip()
```

Regex to find ticket numbers:

```
n = re.search(r'10A-\d{6}',item, re.M|re.I)
```

Comment: is ticket numbers follow a specific pattern?

Comment: @WasiAhmad Yes, I've included the regex code that would find each ticket.

Comment: i have added an answer, hopefully it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your ticket number substring will only contain hyphen `-`, you may use a *dict comprhension* to achieve this like:

```
my_dict = {'8.8.8.8': 'Open Menu  10A-003272 10A-003328 10A-003652', '8.8.8.9': '10A-003069 10/21/2016', '8.8.8.10': 'Open Menu  10A-003145 10/21/2016'}

new = {k: ' '.join(i for i in v.split() if '-' in i) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```

Final value hold by `new` dict will be:

```
{'8.8.8.9': '10A-003069', 
 '8.8.8.10': '10A-003145', 
 '8.8.8.8': '10A-003272 10A-003328 10A-003652'}
```

Comment: @someGuy45: now you can also upvote an answer besides accepting it.

Comment: @someGuy45 what is the point of using regular expression then?

Answer (score 1):

I have updated my answer to print the dictionary in desired format.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'10A-\d{6}')
info = {'8.8.8.8': 'Open Menu  10A-003272 10A-003328 10A-003652', 
        '8.8.8.9': '10A-003069 10/21/2016', 
        '8.8.8.10': 'Open Menu  10A-003145 10/21/2016'}

output = {}
for key, value in info.items():
    tokens = value.split()
    val = ''
    for token in tokens:
        if pattern.match(token):
            val = val + token + ' '
    val = val.strip()
    output[key] = val;

print(output)
```

It prints:

```
{'8.8.8.8': '10A-003272 10A-003328 10A-003652', 
 '8.8.8.9': '10A-003069', 
 '8.8.8.10': '10A-003145'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = { k, clean_ticket(v) for k,v in original_dict.items() if is_ticket(v) }
```

Looks like is_ticket should be something like

```
def is_ticket(v):
    return "Open Menu" in v
```

Make a function clean_ticket(v) that strips off the Open Menu

```
def clean_ticket(v):
    return v.split("Open Menu")[1].strip()
```

Something like that.

Answer (score -2):

I assume you have some function

```
def is_ticket_number(item):
    """ returns True only if item is a ticket number """
    return re.search(r'10A-\d{6}',item, re.M|re.I)
```

Then all you need to do is

```
d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if is_ticket_number(v)}
```